# Got Error when add image download jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am using the below html

```
<div id="pdf_area">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <div><img src="example.png" /></div>
    <div>
        <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chart">
<canvas style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1117px; height: 350px;" width="1117" height="350"></canvas>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="downloadPDF('html')" >Download PDF</a>

<script>
 function downloadPDF(shouldDownload) {
    var funcStr = window.location.hash.replace(/#/g, '') || 'auto';
    var doc = examples[funcStr]();
    doc.setProperties({
        title: 'Example: ' + funcStr,
        subject: 'A jspdf-autotable example pdf (' + funcStr + ')'
    });

    if (shouldDownload) {
        doc.save('table.pdf');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("output").src = doc.output('datauristring');
    }
}
</script>
```

i need to print option and download pdf option with chart, image, tables and html contents.

any one please help me how to download pdf and print in javascript.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's `var doc = examples[funcStr]();` supposed to do? What does that function do? We need it in order to see what's going on and be able to help you.

Comment: By the way, I don't think that jspdf can convert entire html pages into PDF - as far as I see, it lets you create PDF files by manually placing texts and images.

Comment: jsPDF doesn't work correctly with png. Changes are in master, but wasn't released (for a couple of months). Go with jpeg instead or revert back to older version (before 1.3 should work). Don't waste time on png.

Comment: actually my comment above is about addImage, but check jpeg as well

Comment: also please post your error here. Maybe I'm not about your error :)

Comment: i am using another example.js file 

examples.html = function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    doc.text("From HTML", 40, 50);
    var elem = document.getElementById("pdf_area");
    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {startY: 60});
    return doc;
};

Comment: Any other javascript is there to download the pdf with the div id selection?